# Gulp не находит модули

Tags: gulp

Недавно настроил gulp и при работе с первым проектом проблем не было. Проблема возникла на стадии переноса gulp в другой проект. Перенёс gulp, src, и package.json, запустил папку в VScode, после чего использовал npm i для установки плагинов. Но затем, при использовании в терминале непосредственно "gulp" выходит данное сообщение. [image: Сообщение из терминала] Что с этим можно сделать?

Comment: К слову, все данные папки и файлы я проверил, все они на месте

Comment: Может вам следует выполнить `ncu -u --packageFile package.json` , а потом `npm i`

Comment: @MaxWatson выдаёт ошибку о том, что имя "ncu" не распознано как имя

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Один из плагинов попросту не был установлен. (всё решилось одной командой `npm install webp-converter@2.2.3 --save-dev`